# How to find Chainage of points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing, qchainage

I have two types of Road shape files. Road (Polyline) and important points (waypoints) along the road. Both of these shape files are prepared using GPS. I want to find the chainage of the points. Is it possible using QGIS ?

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish it by using the QGIS plugin [LRS](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/) that enables linear referencing support for QGIS. This would be the work flow:

1. Based on both a line (routes) and a point (for calibration) layer, go to the Calibration tab.

   - Select the line layer with its route field (a field that identifies routes, it's very useful if your line layer has several routes).
   - Select the calibration point layer with its corresponding route (point route value should match with the line route value) and measure field. As you can see, you would need a calibration point layer with at least two points, that could be located at the start and the end of the route, with values of 0 and 15000 in case that the route has 15km.
   - Click on Ok to interpolate M values along the routes.
2. Go to the Measures tab.

   - Select your waypoints layer.
   - Fill the output field names.
   - Click on Ok to get a new (memory) layer which will contain the M value (chainage) of waypoint.
3. Don't forget to save the layer you obtain from 2., since it's a memory (temporal) layer. If you want the M values in your waypoints layer, perform a [table join](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html) between waypoints and the layer you obtained from 2.

In the following screenshot you can see a sample route, a couple of calibration points in blue, and a couple of points along the route (green stars) with their calculated chainage (M value).

[image]

Comment: Not sure why, but I had better luck using a string for the route field than an int